# How to call a vector of seeds in a loop, save the results next to eachother each time the loop runs?

Tags: r, loops, statistics, simulation, random-seed

I have two questions:

1. I am doing a simulation, I wrote the necessary functions and I am generating what I need, inside a loop with the following code:

```
sim_seeds<- as.vector(sample(1:30000, 5, replace = FALSE), mode = "numeric")
save(sim_seeds,file = "~/Desktop/untitled folder/sim_seeds.Rda")
load(file = "~/Desktop/untitled folder/sim_seeds.Rda")

for (i in 1:5) {

load(file = "~/Desktop/untitled folder/sim_seeds.Rda")

seeds=set.seed(sim_seeds[i])

#Generating data using functions had been wrote before

data<-generate_data(seed =seeds )

Y_1<- mean(data$Y)

#estimation

weights<-generate_weights(T1=S1~Year+growth, T2=R1~Age+Sex+HIV, data=data)
w<-weights$w
g<-g_est(data=data)
p1<-g$p1
Q<-Q_est(data=data,w , p1)
mu1_Q<-Q$mu1


#Results
results <- rbind(seeds,Y_1,mu1_Q)
results
}
```

My question is on the seeds part! What I want to do is to generate lets say, 5 different dataset, but I need a seperate seed for each time "for" runs, so I want to create a vector of seeds and then call the ith value each time the loop runs, but when I want to call it inside the loop, it gives a NULL value!

2. The other questions is that, I want the final results to be saved and printed next to each other so that I can compare them. So put it in a simple way, I am generating 5 different data set, so 5 rows of the elements I determined in "results"!

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I don't think that you need to generate a new seed for each loop iteration to obtain different results. set.seed(123) at the beginning of your script is enough I'd say to obtain different results (but same results each time you re-run your script)

Comment: @glagla supervisor s order! She said you should not be assigning a similar sumber for seeds each time you run the loop.

Comment: I think the issue when you do a set.seed at the beginning of the loop with the same seed value. In that case, it reinitialise the random generator and will produce the same numbers. don't do: for (I in 1:5) {set.seed(1); generate_something}, but doing set.seed(1) and then the loop is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.: setting a seed at the beginning is enough to obtain different results at each loop iteration. Edited to illustrate it with the example below

2.: for example:

```
set.seed(123)
seeds = 1:5
results = c()
for (i in 1:5){
  set.seed(1) #this is wrong, produces the same set of values at each loop iteration
  # set.seed(seeds[i]) # works, but is unecessary, setting one seed at the beginning is ok
  # commenting the two lines above is fine, and will generate 5 different vectors of random numbers. 
  x = rnorm(5,0,1)
  results = rbind(results, x)
}
results
```

Comment: Thanks glagla but I have been asked not to assign a similar number for seed, each time the loop runs, it has to be a different number.

Comment: @Aura: I edited the post that it's possible to see the effect of the different options

Comment: I tried what you suggest just now, it keeps a same value for seed each time! Im a newbie in R, but I guess being able to create a random numbers between 1 to 3000 is different than seed= 1:5? Or not?

Comment: yes, it keeps the same value if you run the set.seed(1). If you comment it and uncomment the following line, it won't generate the same values. If you comment both line, it should also do what you want. the way you generate your seeds is not very important here

Comment: By commenting it you mean to put a # before set.seed(123) and then run the seeds=1:5 ?

Comment: Also, when I use seeds=set.seed(seeds[i]) which seeds is a vector, it still gives me null which was the problem at the beginning

Comment: using set.seed(seeds[i]) works for me. Maybe the problem is that you used seeds = set.seed(seeds[i]) instead of simply set.seed(seeds[i]) (no need of the '= ' here)